# How do I separate a game's input from its updating logic?

Tags: haskell, input, game-engine, frp

I am using Haskell to write a simple game / game-engine.

The following is one iteration of my game loop:

```
input <- getInput -- where input is some list of pressed keys
let world' = update world input
-- ... continue with the next iteration
```

The `getInput` function looks like:

```
getInput = do
    w <- getKey $ CharKey 'W'
    q <- getKey $ CharKey 'Q'
    -- ...
    return [("W", w), ...]
```

and the `update` function (inside the `World.hs` file) looks like:

```
update world input = world'
    where world' = -- if w, then do something, if q then do something, etc.
```

As you can see, my input logic is split between my actual `Input.hs` file and my `World.hs` file. The update function shouldn't really need to test for key press (in my opinion).

How do I split my input from my updating logic?

---

I am looking for something like callbacks, I suppose, which can be registered and unregistered at will. Registering `moveForward` to the key press of `W` would be ideal.

I have also looked into netwire - but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around functional reactive programming. If this is a case for FRP, I would appreciate any examples using it, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare an action as a function that transforms the world:

```
type Action = Word -> World
```

And then create actions for things independent of the keys to which you intend to bind them:

```
moveForward :: Action
moveForward world = ...
```

Then, you can pass a list of `(key, action)` pairs to a `doInput` function:

```
doInput :: [(CharKey, Action)] -> World -> IO World
doInput bindings world = foldM checkKey world bindings where
    checkKey world (key, action) = do
        pressed <- getKey key
        return $ if pressed then action world else world
```

So in your main loop, you can do something like:

```
mainloop world = do
    doRender world
    world' <- doInput [(CharKey 'W', moveForward)] world
    mainloop world'
```